# Написала программу и пытаюсь сделать чтоб шарик отскакивал. не получается

Tags: java, swing

в целях изучения Java делаю мини-игру "пинг-понг", сейчас пытаюсь сделать просто что б шарик отскакивал от границ поля(низ, верх, лево, право). Вроде все правильно написал, но когда запускаю приложение шар стоит на месте, никуда ни двигается, перебрала все варианты не знаю уже в чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

У меня имеется 3-и касса: 
Main - рисуем поле, подключаем класс Field, 
Field - поле, сюда будем добавлять все(шарик, игроков, бонусы, 
Ball - сам шар.

Main
Код:

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame f = new JFrame("Pong");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setSize(400, 300);
            f.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            f.add(new Field()); //подключаем наш класс Field
            f.setVisible(true);

        }

    }
```

Field 
Код:

```
public class Field extends JPanel {

    Ball b = new Ball(193, 143); //задаем начальные координаты для шара

    public Field() { 
        Runnable r = b;

        Thread rt = new Thread(r);
        rt.start();

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) { //рисуем шар
        b.draw(g);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Ball 
Код:

```
public class Ball implements Runnable{

    int x, y, xDerection, yDerection;

    Rectangle Ball;

    public Ball(int x, int y){ 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

        Random r = new Random();

        int rDir = r.nextInt(1);
        if(rDir == 0) {
            rDir--;
        }
        setXDerection(rDir);

        int yDir = r.nextInt(1);
        if(yDir == 0) {
            yDir--;
        }
        setYDerection(yDir);

        Ball = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, 7, 7);
    }

    public void setXDerection(int xDir) {
        xDerection = xDir;
    }

    public void setYDerection(int yDir) {
        yDerection = yDir;
    }

    public void movie() { //двигаем шар
        this.x = xDerection;
        this.y = yDerection;

        if(x <= 0) {
            setXDerection(+1);
        }
        if(x >= 385) {
            setXDerection(-1);
        }
        if(y <= 15) {
            setYDerection(+1);
        }
        if(y >= 285) {
            setYDerection(-1);
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) { //рисуем
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.width, Ball.height);
    } 


    public void run() { //запускаем
        try{
            while(true) {
                movie();
                Thread.sleep(3);
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Yuliya" - "написал", "перебрал"?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметила, что написала с  ошибками

Comment: @YuliyaStolyarchuk ахах, вообще без палева)))))))

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы шар двигался, ему надо изменять координаты. А в методе movie им просто назначается +/-1. Подозреваю, что логика подразумевала следующее:

```
 this.x += xDerection;
 this.y += yDerection;
```

Comment: добавлю (просто вырви глаз) - переименуйте метод movie в move... а то у вас шар не двигается, т.к. транслирует фильм